# Unity 3d : Slider values take place on second run when trying to modify scale of prefab clones

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, slider, clone

Title pretty much sums it up. I am trying to adjust the scale of cloned prefabs during runtime, through a UI slider. However on first run the slider doesn't seem to have any effect on them, and on second run the Objects just keep one value from the slider and appear already taller or shorter. I need the slider to adjust the height of the objects dynamically, just as it does on a normal, not cloned, object. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The script works on normal objects, not clones.

Here is my slider method :

```
public void slideScale(float textNumber)
    {
        Vector3 scale = Wall.transform.localScale;
        scale.y = textNumber;
        Wall.transform.localScale = scale;
    }
```

I expected to be able to change the height, while moving the slider. 
A value is being stored and just takes place on second run while the slider still seems not to be affecting anything.

Comment: What is the wall GameObject exactly? Can you display your heirarchy?

Comment: And what is a "run"? Restart of the game? Sounds like you have a reference to the prefab instead of the spawned instance.

Comment: @FredrikSchön you seem to have a good point there

Comment: @Skdy https://imgur.com/a/vmrTdfB

every wall and floor object used to be child of a Maze object which is being built on runtime, but I decoupled them thinking this would be what causes the script problem. However the behaviour is the same so I might just make them childs of Object Maze again.

Comment: @FredrikSchön yes,  I mean restarting the game. Please refer to my screenshots. And yes I am referencing the prefab. How could I reference a clone since it's created on the fly?

Comment: When you create the clone, simply store it in a variable to keep a reference to it. I'll create a quick answer and show you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're modifying the reference to the *Prefab* instead of the *instance* of a prefab (clone, in your words).

Here's how you store the reference to an instance of a prefab:

```
// Spawn an object based on a prefab "Wall" 
// and store the spawned object in variable "instance"
GameObject instance = Instantiate(Wall);

// Modify the instance properties
instance.transform.localScale = scale;
```

Comment: I have already done this in a different script. My maze consists of UpWalls, DownWalls, LeftWalls etc, all instances of the same prefab, the Wall. As you saw in the 2nd screenshot, every spawned object already has a reference to itself where the script lies in the inspector... The problem is that all those objects spawn at runtime so I don't have them available to attach them to the Height script, so this is why I am trying through the prefab Wall. I think we are getting close to the solution though. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The code I wrote will be executed in runtime. Of course you can assign variables in runtime. That's basically what programming is. :)

Comment: I don't disagree with you at all, however I am trying to tell you that the problem is not where you think it is. Every spawned object has already a script for adjusting height and a reference to itself in the inspector. Assigning is working as it should. The instanciation of the Wall object is already done in another script. As far as the reference is concerned I don't have the option to reference every instance of Wall in code, let alone in a height adjusting script because those are 2 separate things. Am I making any sense now ,or does it still sound confusing? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I see! Let's see if we can deduct some clarity, however based on what you've written so far I'm quite confident the issue is that you're modifying the prefab instead of the instance. Firstly: `"Every spawned object has already a script for adjusting height and a reference to itself in the inspector"` doesn't make much sense to me, why would you need a reference to yourself, and how would you set a reference in the inspector in runtime? You don't need an inspector reference to access your own transform. Instead of doing `Wall.transform.localScale` just do `transform.localScale`?

Comment: Secondly. What is a `slider value`?

Comment: `"As far as the reference is concerned I don't have the option to reference every instance of Wall in code"`. Why not? You can do anything you need in code.